# Robots.txt to block a parameter instead of a directory

Tags: google-search, robots.txt, url-parameters

It's my understanding that URLs are of the format example.com/something/somethingelse.

It's my understanding that parameters follow the URL with a question mark example.com?l=fr_FR

My CMS website has language translations that use parameters. The example above is for the French language version of my site.

I would like to block all non english translations from Google Index using robots.txt.

In the blocked URLs tool in GWT I tried to test this:

```
# robots.txt generated at http://www.mcanerin.com
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: ?l=
```

Against the following URL, which appeared as one of the duplicate page titles in HTML improvements.

```
https://example.com/reports/view/884?l=eu
```

This is my first time fiddling with this tool in GWT so I'm not sure if I'm using it right.

The test results for Googlebot says

> Allowed by line 3: Disallow:

I wanted the code to prevent Google indexing any URLs that contain the following string

> ?l=

Here are some examples of URLs I'd like to block from the index. These URLs generate duplicate titles according to GWT.
/reports/view/884?l=km
/reports/view/884?l=ne_NP
/reports/view/884?l=te
/index.php/page/index/12?l=fr_FR&l=hy_AM
/index.php/page/index/12?l=ht_HT&l=bn_BD
/index.php/page/index/12?l=hu_HU&l=hy_AM

Can I tell the robots to exclude URLs with tags that contain

> ?l=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can block URLs that contain `?l=` from being indexed by search engine robots by using the following *robots.txt* directive:

`Disallow: /*?l=`

The `/` indicates the root directory, and `*` is a wildcard for anything up to `?l=`, followed by anything after it.

Comment: Dan, you're the best. Thank you very much again, the test in GWT showed that this did work.

Comment: No problem at all :-) I added a little bit of info just now to explain what it means.

Comment: Plus 1 for a great answer.